# Cannot open file with boost::iostreams::file

Tags: c++, boost

I want to open a file with boost::iostreams::file with this code:

```
 boost::iostreams::file file("test.txt");
 if(!file.is_open()) {
     throw std::runtime_error("Could not open file");
 }
```

But it won't open the file and I don't know why. When I use boost::iostreams::file_sink it works. Maybe you have an idea what's wrong? Did I forget something? I'm using Boost version 1.60

Comment: I have made some tests and find out, that boost::iostreams::file seems only open files which already exist. So I have to create the file before with std::ofstream, then it works. But it should also be created with boost, shouldn't it?

Comment: It uses `std::filebuf` underneath [[1](https://github.com/boostorg/iostreams/blob/develop/include/boost/iostreams/device/file.hpp)] [[2](https://github.com/boostorg/iostreams/blob/71b4ed218754cfa86a062e883755549d86aa57b4/include/boost/iostreams/detail/fstream.hpp)]. Default mode is `in|out`. According to [docs](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_filebuf/open) that causes error when file does not exist. You need to set your open mode appropriately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at [*iostreams/device/file.hpp*](https://github.com/boostorg/iostreams/blob/develop/include/boost/iostreams/device/file.hpp), we can see that the constructor provides default open mode of `in|out`.

```
basic_file( const std::string& path,
            BOOST_IOS::openmode mode =
                BOOST_IOS::in | BOOST_IOS::out,
            BOOST_IOS::openmode base_mode =
                BOOST_IOS::in | BOOST_IOS::out );
```

and that it calls the `open(...)` method with this mode.

```
template<typename Ch>
basic_file<Ch>::basic_file
    ( const std::string& path, BOOST_IOS::openmode mode, 
      BOOST_IOS::openmode base_mode )
{ 
    open(path, mode, base_mode);
}
```

The `open(...)` method then creates a new instance of `impl`, using this mode.

```
template<typename Ch>
void basic_file<Ch>::open
    ( const std::string& path, BOOST_IOS::openmode mode, 
      BOOST_IOS::openmode base_mode )
{ 
    pimpl_.reset(new impl(path, mode | base_mode));
}
```

The implementation uses a [`std::basic_filebuf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_filebuf) for the file I/O.

```
struct impl {
    impl(const std::string& path, BOOST_IOS::openmode mode)
        { file_.open(path.c_str(), mode); }
    ~impl() { if (file_.is_open()) file_.close(); }
    BOOST_IOSTREAMS_BASIC_FILEBUF(Ch) file_;
};
```

The macro being defined in [*iostreams/detail/fstream.hpp*](https://github.com/boostorg/iostreams/blob/71b4ed218754cfa86a062e883755549d86aa57b4/include/boost/iostreams/detail/fstream.hpp):

```
# define BOOST_IOSTREAMS_BASIC_FILEBUF(Ch) std::basic_filebuf<Ch>
```

---

Now, according to the documentation of [`std::basic_filebuf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_filebuf) (or specifically, its [`open(...)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_filebuf/open) method):

> ```
> openmode & ~ate  Action if file already exists    Action if file does not exist 
> ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
> out|in           Read from start                  Error
> ```

In order for it to create a new file when one doesn't already exist, you need to supply an appropriate open mode. In your case this would mean either `in|out|app` or `in|out|trunc`, depending on what you want to happen to an already existing file.